# Firebase: do POST request of received notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notifications through firebase on my Android app and everything works fine, but I would like to use the values from each received notification and POST them to an API (basically storing each notification). Where can I put my POST request so it does the job automatically?

The notifications arrive just fine to the phone in which the app is installed. What I can't do is get their value. In the code I showed above, I have 2 Logs on the OnMessageReceived method, and neither of them print anything, meaning the method probably isn't even called (I think). How can I get the notifications data?

Here's `MyFirevaseMessagingService.java` (which basically has nothing, as you will see):

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                /*scheduleJob();*/
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer to the one question on your post is below, but I'm not sure this is what you've looking for. If it isn't, edit your question to be more specific about what problem you're having with the code you shared, or what problem you get after adding the POST call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the received messages to a cloud API, you should call that API inside the `onMessageReceived` method.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer! I suppose that I should be able to see my Log.d with the message then? I have tried to send a notification and find this log in logcat but nothing shows...

Comment: Please include the exact steps you took (with which any of us can reproduce the problem) in your question. The more concrete (yet short) you can make it, the more likely it is that someone spots what's going wrong.

Comment: I can send notifications through the firebase website. I only give them a title and text. They arrive just fine to the phone in which the app is installed. What I can't do is get their value. In the code I showed above, I have 2 Logs on the OnMessageReceived method, and neither of them print anything, meaning the method probably isn't even called (I think). How can I get the notifications data on Android?

Comment: Again: please add the necessary information in the question, so that others can see it too.